# Elasticsearch high updates index compacting

Tags: elasticsearch

Does ES do a periodic compaction on it's near realtime index? how often the it will occuer?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to call the [optimize API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-optimize.html) yourself.